# Installing nodejs on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I'm new to Linux and I want to know how to install Node.js on Ubuntu 19.04.

I downloaded the node-v12.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz from the website and extracted it, but I'm stuck after that, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you downloaded is the source for NodeJS (I could be wrong). So you'll need to build it yourself.

If you want to do that check this [guide](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md).

---

Otherwise you can check the NodeSource distributions [repo](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) on github.

For Node.js v12.x: run these commands in a terminal window

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```